# Native Join query in springboot data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using the native inner join query in Springboot JPA, and what I have observed is that it is executing two queries, one for the parent and another for the child. Why is it so? Is it possible to execute only the defined native query?

In the query, I have added the condition for the child table, but when it is executing the second query for the child, in the condition I can only see programid, it does not include s.status='Active'. I want to get the parent records whose status is active and the corresponding child records whose status is active, but here I am getting active parent records and active and inactive child records.

Program is a parent entity, and a subprogram is a child entity that has one-to-many relationships.

```
    @Query("select  * from program p inner join subprogram s on p.programid=s.programid and s.status='Active' where p.status='Active' order by lower(p.programname),lower(s.programname),nativeQuery=true)
    
    public List<Program> findActiveProgramAndSubprogram();


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="program")
public class Program{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="PROGRAMID")
private String programId;

@Column(name="PROGRAMNAME")
private String programName;

@Column(name="STATUS")
private String status

@OneToMany(mappedBy="program", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FectchType.EAGER)
private List<Subprogram> subprogram=new ArrayList<>();
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="subprogram")
public class Subprogram{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="SUBPROGRAMID")
private String subprogramId;

@Column(name="SUBPROGRAMNAME")
private String subprogramName;

@Column(name="STATUS")
private String subprogramStatus

@SkipGsonSerialization
@ManyToOne(fetch=FectchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PROGRAMID")
private Program program;
}
```

Comment: Can you add `Program` and `SubProgram` entity class?

Comment: @Prog_G Added Program and SubProgram entity class

Comment: Working if I use EntityGraph. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `FETCH` to get the related entities in a single JPA Query.

Try the below `JPA` Query:

```
@Query("select distinct p from Program p INNER JOIN FETCH p.subprogram s where p.status = 'Active' and s.subprogramStatus = 'Active'")
List<Program> findActiveProgramAndSubprogram();
```

To know how INNER JOIN FETCH works read [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/fetch-join.html).

Comment: Above solution is working fine. Thank you